# How do I access a 2D array in JavaScript, or D3.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, console.log, multidimensional-array

I want to access the data in the second array from the following code:

```
var data = [ ["Team 1", 3], ["Team 2", 6], ["Team 3", 9]];
```

I am trying to access the `"team"` and `"team number"` using the following functions.

```
_Chart._accessors = {
`"team": function(data) { return data[0]; },`
`"current": function(data) { return data[0]; }`    
};
```

When I check the console log team, and current return arrays of two items which is logical.

**My question is how do I access the data inside those arrays?**

Answer (score 1):

The same way as you access the data in the outside of them.

Stick `[index]` on the end of the thing you use to access them.

```
data[0][0] // for example
Chart._accessors.team()[0] // for another example
```