# How to push items into a dynamically created array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm just beginning to code and have learnt only basic codes and I have created arrays dynamically with:

```
 for (var j=0; j<20; j++) {
     this["row"+j] = [];
     for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
         ["row"+j].push("false");
     }
 }
```

but now I want to make it so that I can push items into the previously created row1[], row2[], etc... so that it could be like row1[false, false...] and row2[false, false...] Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access a 2D array in JavaScript, or D3.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817081/how-do-i-access-a-2d-array-in-javascript-or-d3-js)

Comment: First: don't use enumerated properties use a proper Array `this.grid[j]` over `this["row"+j]`. Second `"false" !== false` one is a string, and truthy, the other one is a boolean and falsy. `if("false") console.log("is true"); if(false) console.log("this ain't executed")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create arrays not inside object but like normal arrays you can use `window` and then variable name to create variable.

Normally when you declared varibale in will be inside window object(you can access it without writing `window.{variable name}`). So you can take advantage of `window` to created dynamic variable.

```js
for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
  window["row" + j] = []; //<-----use window to create dynamic array
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    window["row" + j].push("false");
  }
}


row1[0] = "true"; // editing content of array
console.log(row1,row2);
```

In the above we have created 20 variable name `row0,row1,....` and you can directly access it like normal arrays.

Comment: That's very helpful thank you! If I want to check that out of all the elements for one that's not false how would I do that? Say if row3[5] is true how would I be able to check it with a loop function?

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<row3.length;i++){if(row3[i]==="true"){console.log(1);}}`

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what `this` is referring here. Rather I will suggest to create an object and in that object keys will be `["row" + j]`, the value of which will be an `[]` and then inside the nested loop push value to that array

```js
let obj = {};


for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
  obj["row" + j] = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    obj["row" + j].push("false");
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: So if I then want to edit one of the elements in one of the array how would I do that?

Comment: get the key from the object , then its value and the index where you want to edit